# Android ListView OnItemClick Change View Properties

Tags: android, android-listview

**What I have:** A custom listview with a custom adapter, with a custom ListViewItem (which extends LinearLayout)

**What i want to do:** When the listbox item is selected, I want to change the background drawable of the selected view.

**What Happens:** Currently nothing. The Toast does appear as it should, but the Background drawable does not change.  I tried calling View.Invalidate() but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Here is the snippet of code that is supposed to change the drawable:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int index, long arg3) 
{
    Card card = CardVM.GetCurrentCards().get(index);
    card.setBlocked(!card.isBlocked());
    if (card.isBlocked())
    {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluegradient);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Card is now Blocked", 1).show();
    }
    else
    {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greengradient);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Card is now Available", 1).show();
    }
}
```

The toggle functionality does work, if you click on it the first time, it will say "card is now blocked".  The second time shows "Card is now available"... and so on.  The setBackgroundResource simply does not work.

Also, when the list view is populated, the background colors are set correctly (using the same resources and the same function).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

It appears the background DOES change, but ONLY if the screen is forced to re-draw it.  For example, when you click on the first item in the list to turn it blue, you need to scroll down (to get it off the screen) then scroll back up.  THEN it turns blue.  Can we avoid this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()` and maybe something like         `view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_item_selected));`

Edit:

invalidate the layout not the individual view.

Comment: what I posted also works for `onItemClick` as well.  I believe your problem is probably `setBackgroundResource`... use `setBackgroundDrawable`... I know it works, I use it myself.

Comment: I actually tried it as well.  It produced the same outcome. :P

Comment: which view are you invalidating?  invalidate the layout not the individual view.

Comment: the one that we are clicking on.  The view that is returned from the onItemClick event.

Comment: I just found out that if I add this: ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewblockcard);
  l.invalidateViews();  To the end of that block, then it works.  Why would view.invalidate() NOT work?

Comment: peanut you hitting f5 every sec... check my prev comment

Comment: because the controlling view is the listview not the item.

Comment: i would guess it's the way the source is written.  i'm sure if you added individual views to a scroll view it would work as you expected but since you are using an adapter something is different.  check the android source itself to find out for sure.

Comment: many thanks for accepting although it was a collaborative effort ;D

Comment: Well, sometimes all you need is an extra pair of eyes. ;) cheers.